# Logarithm Chart Is WPF ToolKit Graph

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts, wpftoolkit

I want to design a wpf toolkit chart which after certain value show only logarithm values in y-axis? i'm using line series for the chart.
[image: ScreenShot Of Application]

I want logarithm values after 100 in y axis.

Please Help Me Out Of This?

Comment: Sambit, Were you able to find any way out. If so, please share with all of us. At present I  also want to set my Y axis a Log 10 scale & I am stuck up. Can't get any solution working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790212/wpf-chart-y-axis-scale-with-custom-numbers  Answer me if you have the solution.